# Scrapy requests - Callback funtion not being called in nested requests

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape some products from amazon in order to get some information on my competitors. This is the process I am adopting:

```
Make a query in the search bar ->
Visit every product page of the results gotten from the query -> 
Gather information from that product ->
Check if the product matches the quantity that we looked for (I.E. We might want to collect only products sold in a pack of n items ... like a kit of n toner cartridges)
    -> If it does, yield the item.
    -> If not, find a variation in that ad that represents a pack of such n items
         -> If such a variation exists, go visit that variation of the product, modify some information of the item (such as price and asin) and yield that item.
```

I have a particular case here. I will not post the entire functions I have but I will rather post some representative functions instead (**in order to keep it shorter and more general so that maybe it is going to be useful to someone else in the future**).

Here is the structure of my code:

```
def start_requests(self):
        for i, prod in enumerate(products):
            url = 'https://www.amazon.it/s?' + urlencode({'k': prod['query']})
            competitors = scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_keyword_response, meta={'prod':prod})
            yield competitors


def parse_keyword_response(self, response):
        # Function that loops on the results of the query made, 
        # and collects all the products that actually match our search
        products = response.xpath('//*[@data-asin]')
        prod = response.meta['prod']

        competitors =[]

        for product in products:
            asin = product.xpath('@data-asin').extract_first()
            product_url = f"https://www.amazon.it/dp/{asin}"
            competitor = scrapy.Request(url=product_url, callback=self.parse_competitor_product_page, meta={'asin': asin, 'prod':prod})
            yield competitor
            competitors.append(competitor)


def parse_competitor_product_page(self, response):
        # Function that scrapes information from a product page and yields the competitor
        # only if it actually matches our search.

        ' Do some work and scrape required product attributes'

        competitor = ProductItem()
        competitor['product'] = prod_name
        competitor['asin'] = asin
        competitor['Title'] = title
        competitor['producer'] = producer
        competitor['MainImage'] = image
        competitor['Rating'] = rating
        competitor['NumberOfReviews'] = number_of_reviews
        competitor['price'] = price
        competitor['AvailableSizes'] = sizes
        competitor['AvailableColors'] = colors
        competitor['Varieties'] = varieties
        competitor['BulletPoints'] = bullet_points
        competitor['SellerRank'] = seller_rank

        if self.is_right_product(prod, competitor, response):
            yield competitor

def is_right_product(self, product, competitor, response):
       # Function that checks whether a resulting competitor actually matches the product that 
       # we looked for. It returns a boolean if it does. It also alters some attributes of that
       # competitor if a right variation is found on its page.

      ' I will omit some if else branches as those work well and I will only post the faulty 
           branch (which happens to be the one that should modify the competitor object because 
           a right variation is found on its page. '

      if product_is_right_quantity(competitor):
           return True
      else:
           variation = find_variation_of_right_quantity(product['quantity'], competitor)
           if vatiation is not None:
                competitor = self..update_product_to_right_variation(competitor, variation, response)
                print("variation check done")
                return True
           else:
                return False

def update_product_to_right_variation(self, product, variation_name, response):
        print("IN UPDATE PRODUCT TO RIGHT VARIATION")
        variation_asin = response.xpath(f'//div[@id="variation_color_name"]/ul/li[contains(@title, \'{variation_name}\')]/@data-defaultasin').get()
        product_url = f"https://www.amazon.it/dp/{variation_asin}"
        print(product_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=product_url, callback=self.update_competitor_from_product_page, errback=self.errback_http, meta={'prod':product, 'asin':variation_asin})

def update_competitor_from_product_page(self, response):
        print("INSIIDE UPDATE COMPETITOR FROM PRODUCT PAGE")
        prod = response.meta['prod']
        asin = response.meta['asin']

        price = response.xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]/text()').extract_first()

        prod['price'] = price
        prod['Title'] = title
        prod['asin'] = asin

        response.meta['prod'] = prod
        print(prod['price'])
        return prod
```

As you can see I placed some print statements for debugging purposes.

**The print statements in  update_competitor_from_product_page never get output**.

All the others do. So that function that should be used as a callback function of the request made in update_product_to_right_variation never gets called.  As a consequence, the competitor object remains unchanged.

I am new to async programming and new to Scrapy as well.

First of all, I would like to know why my callback function never gets called. Secondly, how can I do what I have in mind?

Comment: use `print()` in function which runs `update_competitor_from_product_page` to see if it executes it. I see typo in your code - first you have `variation = ...` but later you check `if vatiation ...`  - and it can get error so it doesn't execute `update_product_to_right_variation` which runs `Requests` with `update_competitor_from_product_page`.

Comment: use `print()` to debug all code - not only last element - and check if all functions are executed to get this data.

Comment: you have to use `meta` to send all product's data to next function and last function should yield/return all product data. You can't send it back to function which yield `Request` and `response.meta['prod'] = prod` is also useless

Comment: Print statements get executed everywhere but in the last function (```update_competitor_from_product_page```). The typo about variation is not the problem as in my original function it is not present... I just mistook typing it here.
And if you look well I also have used meta to send the item to the last function ... :
``` yield scrapy.Request(url=product_url, callback=self.update_competitor_from_product_page, errback=self.errback_http, meta={'prod':product, 'asin':variation_asin})```

Comment: if you get text from `print(product_url)` before `Request(url=product_url, callback=self.update_competitor_from_product_page,..)` then can be only one explanation - you use URL which was already used. Scrapy remebers visited URLs and it never visit the same URL again. You would need `Request(..., don_filter=True)` to visit the same url again.

Comment: you could create minimal working code which we coult test. When I tried to create minimal working code to test it I see other problem - in `parse_competitor_product_page()` you send data to `is_right_product()` which sends it to `update_product_to_right_variation()` and it uses `yield Request` - but `yield/return` doesn't send it to scrapy's engine but only to previous function - it means  from `update_product_to_right_variation()` to `is_right_product()` which should `yield/return` it to `parse_competitor_product_page()` and it should `yield` it and  then it will send it to scrapy's engine.

Comment: Problem is that in one place you use `return True`/`return False` and it doesn't send `Request` to previous function and it can't send `Request` to scarpy's engine - so it doesn't send request and doesn't scrape data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it but problem can be that you try to `yield Request` in function `parse_competitor_product_page()` which is executed in function `is_right_product()` which is executed in `parse_competitor_product_page()` - but `yield`/`return` in function `parse_competitor_product_page()` can't send it directly to Scrapy Engine but it sends it to previous function `is_right_product()` which should `yield`/`return` it to previous function `parse_competitor_product_page()` - and in `parse_competitor_product_page()` you should `yield` it and then it will send it it `Scrapy` Engine which will execute it.

In your code you `yield Request` from `parse_competitor_product_page()` to `is_right_product()` but in `is_right_product()` you send `return True`/`return False` so it doesn't send `Request` to `parse_competitor_product_page()` and it can't send it to Scrapy engine

---

I think you need something like this

```
def parse_competitor_product_page(self, response):
    # Function that scrapes information from a product page and yields the competitor
    # only if it actually matches our search.

    ' Do some work and scrape required product attributes'

    competitor = ProductItem()
    competitor['product'] = prod_name
    competitor['asin'] = asin
    competitor['Title'] = title
    competitor['producer'] = producer
    competitor['MainImage'] = image
    competitor['Rating'] = rating
    competitor['NumberOfReviews'] = number_of_reviews
    competitor['price'] = price
    competitor['AvailableSizes'] = sizes
    competitor['AvailableColors'] = colors
    competitor['Varieties'] = varieties
    competitor['BulletPoints'] = bullet_points
    competitor['SellerRank'] = seller_rank

    variaton = self.is_right_product(prod, competitor):
    if variation is True or variation is None:
        # send to Scarpy's Engine: ProductItem without changes
        yield competitor
    else:
        # send to Scarpy's Engine: Request to page with variation
        yield self.update_product_to_right_variation(competitor, variation)


def is_right_product(self, product, competitor):
    # Function that checks whether a resulting competitor actually matches the product that 
    # we looked for. It returns a boolean if it does. It also alters some attributes of that
    # competitor if a right variation is found on its page.

    '''I will omit some if else branches as those work well and I will only post the faulty 
       branch (which happens to be the one that should modify the competitor object because 
       a right variation is found on its page. '''

    if product_is_right_quantity(competitor):
        return True  # it will assing `True` to `variaton = ...` in `parse_competitor_product_page()`
    
    # it will assing `variation` or `None` to `variaton = ...` in `parse_competitor_product_page()`
    return find_variation_of_right_quantity(product['quantity'], competitor)


def update_product_to_right_variation(self, competitor, variation_asin):
    print("IN UPDATE PRODUCT TO RIGHT VARIATION")
    
    variation_asin = response.xpath(f'//div[@id="variation_color_name"]/ul/li[contains(@title, \'{variation_name}\')]/@data-defaultasin').get()
    
    product_url = f"https://www.amazon.it/dp/{variation_asin}"
    
    print(product_url)
    
    # send back to `parse_competitor_product_page()`
    return scrapy.Request(url=product_url,
                          callback=self.update_competitor_from_product_page,
                          errback=self.errback_http,
                          meta={'prod':competitor, 'asin':variation_asin})


def update_competitor_from_product_page(self, response):
    print("INSIIDE UPDATE COMPETITOR FROM PRODUCT PAGE")
    prod = response.meta['prod']
    asin = response.meta['asin']

    price = response.xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]/text()').extract_first()
    #title = ...
    
    prod['price'] = price
    prod['Title'] = title
    prod['asin'] = asin

    #response.meta['prod'] = prod # useless
    print(prod['price'])
    
    # send to Scarpy's Engine: item with changes
    yield prod
```